# Title and Author Name under every Slide in Metropolis Theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning, presentations

I would like to know how I can add my presentation title, its date, and my name in footline of every slide using Metropolis theme, just like in Warsaw or Madrid themes, for example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using `\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{The title of the presentation}
\author{Anonymous}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertdate{} -- \insertshortauthor{} -- \insertshorttitle}

\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Sample}
Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. This works perfect with me, but I have a further question please: I need to shorten the author name and title in the footline, is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please create a new question for this.

Comment: I already did here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641458/shortening-authors-name-and-presentation-title-in-a-metropolis-footling
. Thanks