# Shortening Author's Name and Presentation Title in a Metropolis Footling

Tags: beamer, formatting, header-footer, presentations

Using Metropolis beamer, I want to add a shorten version of my name and the presentation title. if I apply the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{The title of the presentation}
\author{Anonymous Anonymous}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertdate{} -- \insertshortauthor{} -- \insertshorttitle}

\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Sample}
Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

it shows me the full name the the full title. I would like to know please how I can shorten both, my name and the presentation title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the optional arguments to `\title` and `\author`:

```
\title[Shortitle]{The title of the presentation} 
\author[Shortname]{Anonymous Anonymous}
```